# Steps to integrate google shopping in my website

Tags: google-checkout, google-shopping

I searched a lot in the google.But no luck for me.When i searched for this it automatically redirecting to another page which is for google checkout.I heard that they both are different.But why it is redirecting to that only.

Please help me.Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

This [Google Commerce Developers Page](https://developers.google.com/commerce/) should clarify  and/or differentiate the options/API Google offers for shopping and payment flows/services.

p.s. I won't be a -1 trigger finger but can't say about others who might do so because this really isn't a programming question....